# I want to hide shipping method step no 3 in checkout if free shipping available

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout

I want to hide shipping method step only if there is free shipping.

we are giving free shipping only if cart value is less than 10000

I am new in Magento so tell me all step to customise this page.

Comment: is free shipping for all products or some ?

Comment: if cart value is greater than 1000

Comment: than please update the question with real requirement

Comment: I want to skip 3rd step of shipping method if free shipping available (cart value is greater than 10000)

Comment: Check the link to fulfill your requirement for hiding shipping: [http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-hide-shipping-method-on-magento-frontend-but-leave-it-on-in-admin-area/](http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-hide-shipping-method-on-magento-frontend-but-leave-it-on-in-admin-area/)